# How to center font awesome icons when they get pushed back to the next row?

Tags: html, css

I couldn't find a solution to this online. I'm really struggling to align the icons to be in the middle once they get pushed down to the next row:

[image: image of icons]

```html
<div class="nav-icons">
    <i class="fa-brands fa-java fa-2x text-center"></i>
    <i class="fa-brands fa-js fa-2x text-center"></i>
    <i class="fa-brands fa-python fa-2x text-center"></i>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-c fa-2x text-center"></i>
    <i class="fa-brands fa-html5 fa-2x text-center"></i>
    <i class="fa-brands fa-css3 fa-2x text-center" style="color: lightcyan"></i>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-database fa-2x text-center"></i>
</div>
```

```css
.nav-icons {
    margin-right: 0.5rem;
    margin-left: 0.5rem;
    margin-top: 0.3rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.3rem;
}

.nav-icons i {
     margin: center;
     float: none;
     margin-left: 2rem;
     margin-top: 0.3rem;
     margin-bottom: 0.3rem;
}
```

Comment: Maybe add text-align: center to parent element?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use `text-align:center`?

```css
.nav-icons {
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
  margin-top: 0.3rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.3rem;
  border: 2px solid black width:60px;
  text-align: center
}

.nav-icons i {
  float: none;
  margin: center;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  margin-top: 0.3rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-icons">
  <i class="fa-brands fa-java fa-2x text-center">1</i>
  <i class="fa-brands fa-js fa-2x text-center">2</i>
  <i class="fa-brands fa-python fa-2x text-center">3</i>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-c fa-2x text-center">4</i>
  <i class="fa-brands fa-html5 fa-2x text-center">5</i><br>
  <i class="fa-brands fa-css3 fa-2x text-center" style="color: cyan">6</i>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-database fa-2x text-center">7</i>






</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

hello you can try with this code. it will help you. i have use method with `flex`

```css
.nav-icons {
 background:red;
  display:-webkit-box;
  display:-ms-flexbox;
  display:flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-pack:center;
  -ms-flex-pack:center;
  justify-content:center;
 box-sizing:border-box;
}

.nav-icons i {
  padding:10px;
  width:25%;
  background:blue;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-icons">
  <i class="fa-brands fa-java fa-2x ">icon 1</i>
  <i class="fa-brands fa-js fa-2x ">icon 2</i>
  <i class="fa-brands fa-python fa-2x">icon 3</i>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-c fa-2x">icon 4</i>
  <i class="fa-brands fa-html5 fa-2x">icon 5</i>
  <i class="fa-brands fa-css3 fa-2x">icon 6</i>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using below code,

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

.nav-icons {
background-color:grey;
  border: 2px solid black width:60px;
   text-align: center;
}

.nav-icons i {
color:black;
background-color:lime;
line-height:3;
padding:13px 13px;
border:1px solid lightblue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="nav-icons">
  <i class="fa-brands fa-java fa-2x text-center">1</i>
  <i class="fa-brands fa-js fa-2x text-center">2</i>
  <i class="fa-brands fa-python fa-2x text-center">3</i>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-c fa-2x text-center">4</i>
  <i class="fa-brands fa-html5 fa-2x text-center">5</i><br>
  <i class="fa-brands fa-css3 fa-2x text-center">6</i>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-database fa-2x text-center">7</i>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You have to insert `text-align: center;` only for alignment.

For more reference visit this link : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp